# Skill-based ranking system with individual performance

Tags: bayesian, standard-deviation, ranking, elo

I am attempting to rank players in an online game and have successfully used TrueSkill to create a good ranking system however I would like to take it a step further and let individual performance account for some of the rating gained/lost.

The major factor I see is that its hard to use individual performance as each player could have a different role in the team and their impact on the game is not necessarily represented fairly. I have been thinking and I have an idea but I'm by no means a stats guy and would like some input.

My Idea is that I could assign scores to a number of different stats that would try to award points fairly for each function of the team for example, kills, deaths, survivability, game impact.

I could then find the average of these scores over all games giving me the scores of an "average" player. For each player in a match I would then find the standard deviation from the average player and modify the True Skill rating by that amount.

In my head this means that a player who is playing better than the average but still loses will lose less rating than a player that is playing worse and losing. I'm just concerned that by doing this I will invalid the way TrueSkill works.

Any thoughts would be great!